# How to pass labels and not values with Gravity Forms Checkbox URL Query Parameters

Tags: wordpress, checkbox, gravityforms

I need to pass a list of labels into a Wordpress form to create checkboxes, preferably Gravity Forms. I know you can use: "Allow field to be populated dynamically" but that only populates the value and doesn't make a list of checkboxes dyncamically. Eg: yahoo.com/?CheckboxLabels=yellow&green&red

Checkboxes:

1. yellow
2. green
3. red

Is there a way to accomplish this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will resolve your problem. check the link

https://www.gravityhelp.com/forums/topic/dynamically-populate-checkboxes?replies=2

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working for me by adding to functions.php in the theme.

```
<?php
//NOTE: update the ' 1' to the ID of your form
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render_1', 'populate_checkbox' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_validation_1', 'populate_checkbox' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_submission_filter_1', 'populate_checkbox' );
add_filter( 'gform_admin_pre_render_1', 'populate_checkbox' );



function populate_checkbox( $form ) {

    foreach( $form['fields'] as &$field )  {

        //NOTE: replace 3 with your checkbox field id
        $field_id = 6;
        if ( $field->id != $field_id ) {
            continue;
        }

        $input_id = 1;


        foreach (explode(',', $_GET["addresses"]) as $name => $value) {

            //skipping index that are multiples of 10 (multiples of 10 create problems as the input IDs)
            if ( $input_id % 10 == 0 ) {
                $input_id++;
            }

            $choices[] = array( 'text' => $value, 'value' => $value );
            $inputs[] = array( 'label' => $value, 'id' => "{$field_id}.{$input_id}" );

            $input_id++;
        }

        $field->choices = $choices;
        $field->inputs = $inputs;

    }

    return $form;
}

?>
```